# Remove part of a URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I remove `main/` in `http://domain/main/about`

so the URL will be like this `http://domain/about`

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Well, in the absence of any further details, you could try something like this:

```
RewriteRule (.*)/main/(.*) $1/$2
```

But this is a VERY broad rule - you'd probably want to tune it more tightly than that. Try turning the RewriteLogLevel to 9 and watching the rules as they get processed so you can get a better idea of what is being matched.

Comment: LogLevel to 9?? Why so much? 3 or 4 should be enough for him I guess.

Comment: I just feel that if you're just learning about mod_rewrite, the more data you can get about how the internal states work, the better off you are.

Comment: Hum why not. But 9 could be a little confusing for a first start :P

Answer (score 5):

If you only need one file to be rewritten :

```
RewriteRule main/about about [L]
```

or else the TML answer is good :

```
RewriteRule (.*)/main/(.*) $1/$2 [L]
```

It rewrites **any** URL with a /main (even in third, fourth, ... places) in it to prefix/suffix URL.