# How to remove url segment via web.config?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, web-config

How to remove url segments via web.config rerwrite rules?

Scenarios
Removing en
Example 1
domain.com/en/blog/article1

redirect to
domain.com/blog/article1

Removing fr
Example 2
domain.com/fr/blog/article2

redirect to
domain.com/blog/article2

I'm trying to do both in one redirect rule.

Equivalent to 
[Remove part of a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800203/remove-part-of-a-url)

Comment: means you want  to remove "en" from  url i.e present in web config under which tag.Is it so?

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite the url for the frontend user

Comment: can you please let me know the scenario where and at what place you want to change the url ???

Comment: Hi user1474602 I've added two examples in the question